# How to clear the local nuget package cache using the Cake script

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package, cakebuild

I need to clear the NuGet cached in my system.

I can run the following command in my command prompt.

```
nuget locals -clear all
```

How can I do the same using Cake script.

Please suggest the possible ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no avail wrapper for that nuget command in Cake yet, but you could just as easily just launch that as an process from Cake like this

```
int nugteClear = StartProcess("nuget", "locals -clear all");
if (nugteClear != 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to clear package cache.");
}
```